# Need help to call the java script from c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to format the value as currency like ($1,000), i am having the code with me but i need to know how to call the java script from c#

**aspx.cs page** (code page

```
x= 2345
textbox1.text = x.ToString();// i need the format currency here
```

**JavaScript**

```
function formatCurrency(num)
 {
    num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g,'');
    if(isNaN(num))
    num = "0";
    sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
    num = Math.floor(num*100+0.50000000001);
    cents = num%100;
    num = Math.floor(num/100).toString();
    if(cents<10)
    cents = "0" + cents;
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length-(1+i))/3); i++)
    num = num.substring(0,num.length-(4*i+3))+','+
    num.substring(num.length-(4*i+3));
    return (((sign)?'':'-') + '$' + num + '.' + cents);
}
```

Please help me how to call the format currency from c# file , I need to display the format value in text box.

Comment: Why not formating in C# ?

Comment: thats a specific format like customized format . so i need to use the format

Comment: Assuming for the sake of argument that C#'s built in number and string formatting methods can't cope with your custom format, why not write an equivalent to the above function in C#? The function isn't doing anything you can't easily duplicate (if anything I'd say it's already more complicated than it needs to be to get that result).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this type of code in c#. I dont think you need javascript to format the currency value.

```
decimal somemoney = 2345m;
string html = String.Format("{0:C}", somemoney);
textbox1.text = html;
```